# How to only allow a value from a predefined set of constants?

Tags: c++, class, typedef

I have `color` class template, some `typedef`s on it, and a bunch of color constants:

```
template<typename T>
class color
{
public:
    color(T data) : data(data) {}
    // other functions...
private:
    T data;
};
typedef color<uint16_t> color16;
typedef color<uint32_t> color32;

typedef color16 guicolor;
const guicolor WHITE = 0xFFFF;
const guicolor BLACK = 0x000F;
// other colors...
```

I also have some functions which *should* take one of the predefined `guicolor` constants, for example:

```
void foo(guicolor Color) { ... }
```

However, `foo` also accepts other instances of the `color<uint16_t>` class than just the predefined `guicolor` constants, which is undesirable because you should only be able to use the predefined set of colors that the GUI uses.

I could make `guicolor` a subclass of `color16`, but is it worth it / good practice as I would not add any additional functionality to that class, only use it as a name to differentiate from other `color16` instances? Are there any other solutions to this?

Comment: If you're asking this to solve a problem rather than specifically to learn the answer to your question, you should probably elaborate upon your constraints; it's not obvious why other instances should be undesirable, nor why you're not using `enum`.

Comment: @Hurkyl I'm not using `enum` because you can't have an `enum` of a class type. Any ideas what else I should add? I think I've already included all the constraints in the question.

Comment: I think the best option is to make a `predefined_color` subclass.  I can't think of any other ideas that come up cleaner.  Other than altering the function to take any color object.  Actually, yeah... do that one.

Comment: You could change your function to take in an enum and perform the conversion internally to a `color`.

Comment: The details don't match the question title. It's not that you only want to allow the typedef, it's that you only want to allow certain values. Please edit.

Comment: @Hurkyl Added the "why other instances should be undesirable" to the question.

Comment: @Hurkyl I just realized what you meant with your comment about using `enum`. The problem is that I should then construct a `color16` using the integral enum value inside `foo`.

Comment: And why is that a problem?

Comment: @Brian Good point. Editing...

Comment: @BenjaminLindley The problem is that there are actually multiple functions that take a `guicolor` (edited the question to reflect that), and it would be cumbersome to have them all do the conversion.

Comment: No, it would also be `an additional functionality to that class` to `use it as a name to differentiate from other color16 instances`. Just subclass it. (*)

Comment: `color16 c = convert(enum_color);` <-- That line, in each function that needs it. You consider *that* cumbersome?

Comment: Actually it seems that I've been thinking about a whole other function than `foo` (one taking a `color16`, not a `guicolor`) while writing this question about `foo`. I probably got mixed up because `guicolor` used to be a simple `enum` of `uint16_t` (typedefed as `color16`) before I converted `color16` to a class.  Actually using an `enum` as suggested by some of you seems to be what I need to be doing with `foo`. Thanks for the comments. I guess this question is meaningless now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the suggestions in the comments can be some possible choices, I know another trick for that.

Instead of defining `guicolor` with `typedef` or subclassing, we can define it as a separated class, with 3 tricks.

```
class guicolor
{
private:
    uint16_t data;

private:    // Trick 1: private constructor!
    guicolor(uint16_t data) : data(data) {}

public:     // Trick 2: custom conversion!
    operator color16() const
    {
        return color16(this->data);
    }

public:     // Trick 3: static members!
    static const guicolor White;
    static const guicolor Black;
};

// Static members need to be *declared* in the class, and *defined* outside.
const guicolor guicolor::White = 0xFFFF;
const guicolor guicolor::Black = 0x0000;
```

Then, the `foo` function is simply what you have written.

```
void foo(guicolor c) { ... }
```

Next is the usage.

```
color16 some_color_1 = 0xF000;  // Normal
color16 some_color_2 = guicolor::White; // guicolor object is implicitly convertible to color16

guicolor some_guicolor_1 = 0x1234;  // Compilation error as expected, due to private constructor.
guicolor some_guicolor_2 = guicolor::White; // Compilation pass, due to the pre-defined static member and compiler generated public copy constructor.

foo(some_color_1);      // Compilation error as expected
foo(some_guicolor_2);   // Compilation pass
```

Comment: Private constructor + in-class static instantiation, nice trick! Thanks, may come in handy some day.